# Proof of Newton's Generalized Binomial Theorem (without Calculus)

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem

I'm writing an article for derivates, I've already prooved Newton's Binomial Theorem, but I want to proof that the expresion
$$(a+b)^r=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\binom{r}{i}a^ib^{r-i}$$
works for all $a,b,r\in\mathbb{R}$, where
$$\binom{r}{i}:=\frac{r(r-1)\cdots(r-(i-1))}{i!}$$

Comment: Proof by induction? Take arbitrary $a,b$, and induct on $r$. Afterwards, you can add an extra step to deal with rationals, and then with $\lim \sup$ of rationals for the reals.

Comment: Without knowledge of analysis, it is impossible because you need to deal with the problem of convergence of infinite series.

Comment: Here $r$ is a real number! You need at least the Taylor-formulae with remainder-term bounds in order to prove this identity. Note also that this is only valid for $|a| < |b|$, otherwise the series is not convergent.

Comment: I mean, you can use calculus, but not anything that requieres derivatives, since the idea is to proof that $\frac{d}{dx}[x^r]=rx^{r-1}$ for all $r\in\mathbb{R}$, infinite series are allowed

Comment: How did you introduce real (especially irrational) powers? Also, you should really edit your post, taking into account the condition from @p4sch 's comment

Comment: @YuriyS I formalized reals with the following method: Let $S=\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$ be the set of all sequencies, then $C\subset S$ is the set of all Cauchy sequencies. We'll write $s\sim t$ where $s,t\in C$ when $\lim_n s_n-t_n=0$, notice $\sim$ is an order relation. Finally $\mathbb{R}:=C^2/\sim$ (the quotient set), and each $r\in\mathbb{R}$ satisfies that is the limit to their defining sequencies

Comment: The question was how do you define $a^r$ for $r \in \mathbb{R}$? If $a>0$ one usually define $a^r = \exp( r \ln(a))$.

Comment: I still haven't defined logarithms, basically the sequence definition for reals allows you to derive all the algebraic properties from new resulting sequences, i.e. supose $\lim_n s_n=r$ then $a^r=\lim_n a^{s_n}$.

Comment: @JoséIgnacioCuevasBarrientos, have you proved that the second limit exists if the first one does? And that the product rule is true for real exponents?

Comment: @YuriyS is not necesary, since $a^{s_i}$ is a new Cauchy sequence, therefore it is a new real number. But I've already proved that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}g(f(x))=g\left(\lim_{x\to c}f(x)\right)$ if that's what you're asking

Comment: $(a+b)^r=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\binom{r}{i}a^ib^{r-i}$ is not valid for all $a,b,r \in \Bbb R$, so you definitely won't find a proof for it.